# How can I send information from my searchview in my main actiity to one of the fragments from my viewpager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, searchview

My main activity has a viewpager with 3 fragments. In fragment1 I have a recyclerview that shows some information. Back into my main activity I have a searchview, my question is how can I pass the information from my mainactivity to the fragment1 so I can update my recyclerview based on what the user put in the searchview.

I already have the searchview and the listener with onQueryTextSubmit and onQueryTextChange methods to get the string from the searchview

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Send data from activity to fragment in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12739909/send-data-from-activity-to-fragment-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `FragmentPagerAdapter` as a bridge. Add a method to your `FragmentPagerAdapter`:

```
public void onQueryTextChange(String text) {
    fragment1.onQueryTextChange(String text);
}
```

In fragment1 you should also add a method:

```
public void onQueryTextChange(String text) {
    //do something
}
```

Then in your `Activity`, when search text changed, call:

```
theAdapter.onQueryTextChange(text);
```